# Javascript dot and bracket vs python bracket notations for accessing elements in nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, python

I was wondering on why Python syntax for accessing elements within a list nested in a dictionary doesn't work in JavaScript.

For example if we have the `myStorage` dictionary/object. And I want to access the element `"maps"`.

```
var myStorage = {
  "car": {
    "inside": {
      "glove box": "maps",
      "passenger seat": "crumbs"
     },
    "outside": {
      "trunk": "jack"
    }
  }
};
```

Why does the Python style command below not work in JavaScript even though it works in Python?

```
myStorage["car"["inside"["glove box"]]];
```

But the dot and bracket notation in javascript works.

```
myStorage.car.inside["glove box"];
```

Comment: Because they are different languages with different syntaxes? In general you shouldn't expect the syntax from one language to work in another even if there is some overlap. This is the same as spoken languages.

Comment: why does console.log() work in js and not in python?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, these are two different languages. The syntax for C vs C++ is also from some part similar as well but it can and will behave differently if you don't know what it does in the background. Same for other languages. Syntax is just set of rules for a programmer to follow so the "machine" be it VM (byte or different), compiler or directly CPU can make use of it somehow.

If you start abstracting from the lowest part i.e. CPU instructions you get to the low-level languages up to high/higher/scripting and through the various abstractions even though the syntax might be similar or even the same (Python / Ruby / Haskell) the engine that makes use of the code will behave differently. Learning the syntax is only one of the steps if you want to code in Python and in JS at the "same" time.

The dot-access in Python is used for `getattr()` in the background and if such attribute is missing, you'll get an `AttributeError` raised. There's no pre-defined value to be returned because Python forces a programmer to be explicit in cases when it matters.

For JavaScript, on the other hand, there is a default value if the attribute is missing i.e. you don't get an error, but the default `undefined`.

The indexing/key-access however can be utilized when using Python's `__dict__` attribute (`thing.__dict__[key]`) or `vars(object)[key]`. By that you can get closer to JS rules such as: `vars(object).get(key, None)`, however some objects don't have `__dict__` (such as C/C++/Cython extensions when written so), therefore in that case you'd need to check also for `__slots__` attribute:

```
def js_access(obj, key, default=None):
    if hasattr(obj, "__dict__"):
        return getattr(obj, key, default)
    elif hasattr(obj, "__slots__"):
        ...
    elif <other cases>:
        ...
```

Same/similar syntax, different rules for execution.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's much clearer now with the background methods explained!